# Python Script called executed from bash script not handling signals

Tags: python, bash, shell

**Problem**: When executing a python script from the command line, it catches and handles SIGTERM signals as expected. However, if the script is called from by a bash script, and then bash script then sends the signal to the python script, it does not handle the SIGTERM signal as expected.

The python script in question is extremely simple: it waits for a SIGTERM and then waits for a few seconds before exiting.

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import sys
    import signal
    import time


    # signal handler
    def sigterm_handler(signal, frame):
        time.sleep(5)
        print("dying")
        sys.exit()

    # register the signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)


    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

If this is called directly and then the signal sent from the command line
i.e.

```
> ./sigterm_tester.py &
> kill -15 <PID>
```

the signal handling performs normally (it waits 5 seconds, posts "dying" to stdout, and exits)

However, if it is instead called from a bash script, it no longer seems to catch the SIGTERM and instead exits immediately.
This simple bash script executes the python script and then kills its child (the python script). However, the termination occurs immediately instead of after a 5 second delay, and there is no printing of "dying" to stdout (or to a file when I attempted stdout redirection).

```sh
    #!/bin/bash

    ./sigterm_tester.py &

    child=$(pgrep -P $$)

    kill -15 $child

    while true;
    do
        sleep 1
    done
```

Some additional information: I have also tested this with sh as well as bash and the same behavior occurs. Additionally I have tested this and gotten the same behavior in a MacOS environment as well as a Linux environment. I also tested it with both python2 and python3.

My question is why is the behavior different seemingly dependent on how the program is called, and is there a way to ensure that the python program appropriately handles signals even when called from a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing @Matt Walck comments. In the bash script you were killing the python process right after invoking it, which might not had enough time to register on the sigterm signal. Adding a `sleep` command between the spawn and the kill command will back the theory up.

```
#!/bin/bash

./sigterm_tester.py &

child=$(pgrep -P $$)

#DEBUGONLY
sleep 2

kill -15 $child

while true;
do
        sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This DOES seem to work. When you say it seems to be killing the process that's invoking the process, what is that process? In the original script, I thought this might be the case so I checked if the process had any children, but it had no children so I assumed it had to be the python program.

Comment: Of further interest, I modified the program to both print out what's returned by $(pgrep -P $$) and $(ps -ef | grep sigterm_tester.py | awk {'print $2'}) and they are the same (minus the additional PID for the grep command). So now I'm very confused why this returns different results

Comment: Updated the answer with some prints that hopefully explain what's happening.

Comment: So I just did some further testing, and it is not actually the problem of killing the invoking process: it's a good old fashioned race condition. The originating process is too fast and kills it. However, your process with all of the redirection seems to have given the other process enough time to load the library and register the signal handler. You can see this if you add "echo $(ps -ef | grep sigterm_tester | awk {'print $2'})" under where you have echo $child, or if you add sleep 1 right before I kill the child in my original script

Comment: If you'd like to edit your answer accordingly I'm happy to accept your answer, you were invaluable in finding the problem. I've been banging my head against this for hours. Or I can edit it, either way, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: #Matt I edited the answer for future reference. Thanks.